# Creating a new Object from a Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to build an object that works like the Buffer object in NodeJS.

```
function Header (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.fromBuffer = function(b)
    {
        console.log(X);
    };
}

var b  = Buffer.alloc(16);
var hd = Header.fromBuffer(b);
```

This code does not work at all.
I want to create a new Header object, that loads its data from a Buffer.
How is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: `ArrayBuffer` is the closest thing to Nodes, Buffer, but I'm unsure what your trying to do.

Comment: fromBuffer() is not defined as a static function on the Header class, so you need to make a header instance instead of using Header.fromBuffer() .

Comment: i just called it fromBuffer, it has nothing to do with the Buffer object. i can also call it Header.LoadStuffFromBuffer();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your buffer contains JSON data, you can do this:

```
function Header (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.fromBuffer = function(b)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(b.toString());
        this.type = data.type;
        this.color = data.color;
        return this;
    };

  return this;
}

var b  = new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({type:"1", color: "blue"}));
var hd = new Header().fromBuffer(b);  
console.log(hd);
```

Output:

```
Header { type: '1', color: 'blue', fromBuffer: [Function] }
```

If you have only string data in your buffer (assuming it's the color), you can just call `b.toString()`

```
function Header (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.fromBuffer = function(b)
    {
        this.color = b.toString();
        return this;
    };

    return this;
}

var b  = new Buffer.from("blue");
var hd = new Header(1).fromBuffer(b);
console.log(hd);
```

Comment: Looks good but is not really the same. Let me explain: i want o have something like https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html  Buffer.from(xy);. i want to create a new Header object, and load the data from a buffer or something like that

Comment: @Bob it's not clear...what is the format of your Buffer ?

Comment: var b = new Buffer.alloc(16); is a binary buffer filled with zeros. if you want to create a new buffer called b you call the function Buffer.alloc(16) to do so. how can i create a custom object, called header? var hd = new Header.from(something). how does that prototype should look like?

Comment: ok, so how do you want to obtain a color name from zeroes? You first need to know what's in the Buffer to extract data from it.

Comment: no color, i only need to find a way to create a new Header object. it can be a string, a color or what ever. i just want to know how i can get out a function that can be called like this: "var hd = new Header.LoadFromX(some buffer/or color/or whatever);

Comment: see my updated answer...you just need to `return this` from your `Header` function and also from `fromBuffer`